# How to place 2 input fields on the same row?

Tags: html, css

In my contact form, I'd like to place the input fields first name and last name next to each other on the same line. What would be the best way to do that?
Many thanks,

See https://jsfiddle.net/xrx89Lr0/

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="contact-container clearfix">
  <form class="clearfix" id="contactfrm" method="post" name="contactfrm">
    <input class="_input-1 floatlabel input-40px" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Your first name" type="text">
    <input class="_input-1 floatlabel input-40px" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Your last name" type="text">
    <input class="_input-2 floatlabel" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Votre adresse e-mail" type="email">
    <textarea class="floatlabel" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Votre message et votre numéro de téléphone"></textarea>
    <button class="wow fadeInUp" name="submit" type="submit" value="Envoyer"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> SEND&nbsp;</button>

  </form>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.contact-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

form {
  left: 0;
  /* margin: 35px auto auto; */
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-right-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-bottom-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-left-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-left-style: dotted;
  background-color: #efefef;
  line-height: 1.38;
  color: #444444;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -o-animation-direction: alternate;
  /*border: 2px solid #EFEFEF;*/
}

.input-40px,
.textarea-40px {
  width: 40% !important;
}

form input:focus,
form textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #b9e22d;
}

.contact-container ._input-1 {
  height: 38px;
  margin-top: 17px;
}

.contact-container ._input-2 {
  height: 38px;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

.contact-container ._input-3 {
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

textarea {
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
```

Comment: `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by applying css rule 
display:inline-block to those input fields.

With this you will allow other elements to sit to their left and right side, plus you can apply margin and paddings to element and apply width and height values.

Answer (score 1):

add this in css

```
input, textarea {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this styles.

```
.contact-container ._input-1 { float: left; margin-bottom: 20px; }
.input-40px, .textarea-40px { width: 44% !important; }
input, textarea { width: 95%; margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.input-40px{display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try by applying css rule display:inline-block to those input fields.

display: inline;

Answer (score 0):

use `display:inline-block` as well as `box-sizing:border-box` in `input, textarea` as when you give padding `10px` from left and right and `width:100%` then the actual width is `100% + 20px`. Use `box-sizing:border-box` it will merge the padding in width and width will remain `100%` even after padding.

```css
.contact-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
form {
  left: 0;
  /* margin: 35px auto auto; */
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
input,
textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-right-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-bottom-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-left-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-left-style: dotted;
  background-color: #efefef;
  line-height: 1.38;
  color: #444444;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -o-animation-direction: alternate;
  /*border: 2px solid #EFEFEF;*/
}
.input-40px,
.textarea-40px {
  width: 49% !important;
}
form input:focus,
form textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #b9e22d;
}
.contact-container ._input-1 {
  height: 38px;
  margin-top: 17px;
}
.contact-container ._input-2 {
  height: 38px;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
.contact-container ._input-3 {
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
textarea {
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-container clearfix">
  <form class="clearfix" id="contactfrm" method="post" name="contactfrm">
    <input class="_input-1 floatlabel input-40px" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Your first name" type="text">
    <input class="_input-1 floatlabel input-40px" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Your last name" type="text">
    <input class="_input-2 floatlabel" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Votre adresse e-mail" type="email">
    <textarea class="floatlabel" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Votre message et votre numéro de téléphone"></textarea>
    <button class="wow fadeInUp" name="submit" type="submit" value="Envoyer"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> SEND&nbsp;</button>

  </form>
</div>
```